# Enum list to STL container

Tags: c++, stl, enums

Can someone improve upon this function of mine?  enumToSTLContainer is to return any STL container whose elements are from a specified enum list.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <set>

enum MyEnum {A, B, C, D, E, FirstMyEnum = A, LastMyEnum = E};

template <typename CONTAINER>
CONTAINER enumToSTLContainer (typename CONTAINER::value_type first, typename CONTAINER::value_type last) {
    CONTAINER v;
    for (typename std::underlying_type<typename CONTAINER::value_type>::type N = first;  N <= last;  N++)
        v.push_back(static_cast<typename CONTAINER::value_type>(N));  // But only works for STL containers with push_back defined.
    return v;
}

int main() {
    const std::vector<MyEnum> enumVector = enumToSTLContainer<std::vector<MyEnum>> (FirstMyEnum, LastMyEnum);
    for (MyEnum x : enumVector)
        std::cout << x << ' ';  // 0 1 2 3 4
//  const std::set<MyEnum> enumSet = enumToSTLContainer<std::set<MyEnum>> (FirstMyEnum, LastMyEnum);  // won't compile
}
```

Problems with the above.  Only works for STL containers with push_back defined, need to specify first and last element of the enum list, does not work if enum values are not consecutive, ...

Perhaps obtain an initializer_list using variadic templates, which can then return the desired STL container?  Make a tuple out of the enum using std::integer_sequence, or make your own integer_sequence corresponding to the enum elements in case they are not consecutive?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about improving code and would be better served on http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: What would you want for a range with discontinuities like `enum {a, b=100};`?

Comment: That's why my function needs serious improvement to work in general.  @Captain Oblivious, my code is only a (poor) suggestion to a solution to start things off.  I'm actually asking for ideas and how-to.

Comment: This is not possible. There is no construct in C++ with the semantic of "take all possible/named values of this enum and do something with them".

Comment: Can we make a tuple out of the enum using std::integer_sequence and obtain a pack using the initializer_list feature of variadic templates?

Comment: Well, we can. We still need to specify the first and the last value, and it will still fail on non-consecutive values, but at least it will be a compile-time construct.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I got the desired property with the following, but it uses the assumption that the enum underlying values start at zero and are consecutive.  The solution is in C++11 rather than C++14 so that everyone here should be able to compile it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <set>

enum MyEnum {A, B, C, D, E, NumElements};

template <std::size_t...> struct index_sequence {};

template <std::size_t N, std::size_t... Is>
struct make_index_sequence_helper : make_index_sequence_helper<N-1, N-1, Is...> {};

template <std::size_t... Is>
struct make_index_sequence_helper<0, Is...> {
    using type = index_sequence<Is...>;
};

template <std::size_t N>
using make_index_sequence = typename make_index_sequence_helper<N>::type; 

template <typename RETURN_TYPE, std::size_t... TYPES>
inline RETURN_TYPE helper (index_sequence<TYPES...>) {
    return {static_cast<typename RETURN_TYPE::value_type>(TYPES)...};
}

template <typename CONTAINER, std::size_t N>
CONTAINER enumToSTLContainer() {
    return helper<CONTAINER> (make_index_sequence<N>());
}

int main() {
    const std::vector<MyEnum> enumVector = enumToSTLContainer<std::vector<MyEnum>, NumElements>();
    for (MyEnum x : enumVector)
        std::cout << x << ' ';  // 0 1 2 3 4
    const std::set<MyEnum> enumSet = enumToSTLContainer<std::set<MyEnum>, NumElements>();
    std::cout << "\n\n";
    for (MyEnum x : enumSet)
        std::cout << x << ' ';  // 0 1 2 3 4
}
```

So with this second solution, we are no longer restricted to STL containers that have push_back.  Would appreciate if someone could show me how to improve this solution where the enum underlying values are not consecutive.  Ideally NumElements should not be needed either.  I presume only make_index_sequence_helper needs to be modified according the MyEnum underlying values?

The only generalization that I could come up with is the lousy:

```
template <typename CONTAINER, std::size_t... Is>
CONTAINER enumNonContiguousToSTLContainer() {
    return helper<CONTAINER> (index_sequence<Is...>());
}
```